# Can i store document.getElementById('id').value in a variable in php like this

Tags: php

```
<?php $id= "document.getElementById('id').value" ;

$id= "document.getElementById('id').value";
?>
```

Actually i want to do

```
document.form.action='".HTTP_PATH."search_list.php/".$id."/".$city."';
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't store the JS variable in PHP like that.

The javascript will run after the PHP is run and returned by Apache, so the PHP variable won't exist at that point.

However, Your second example is possible (on the face of it)

```
formReference.action = '<?php echo HTTP_PATH . "search_list.php/" . $id . "/" . $city ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're simply storing the String "document.getElementById('id').value" in **$id**. PHP is server-side which means it runs before your JavaScript and simply generates output to your document.